# Android embossed border for tablerow

Tags: android, border, android-linearlayout, tablerow, emboss

I want to add an embossed border for the TableRow and LinearLayout like below. How can I add it?

[image: Embossed border]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can  use this type of row or simply between two rows:

```
    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#ABABAB"
   />
```

Comment: It will not work for me, as I have to add some vertical border. Moreover it is not actually not looking as embossed.

Comment: better you can use shape(customised view) for embossed table row border

Comment: I use small image strip to give proper effect...it is now working fine.